# PHP POST script works with other sites but not with iOS NSURLConnection

Tags: php, ios, post, nsurlconnection

I've tried my best to fix it but I can't find the problem. Here's the code

iOS:

```
- (IBAction)login {
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"user=%@&pass=%@", _username, _password];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/login.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_responseData appendData:data];
    NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", stringData);
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo "Username: ".$_POST["user"]."<br>Password: ".$_POST["pass"];
?>
```

This returns the following:

```
Username: <br>Password:
```

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with it for hours. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check what is actually being sent and received with Charles Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
@interface Test : NSObject
-(void)userLogin;
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Test *test = [[Test alloc] init];
        [test userLogin];
    }
    return 0;
}

@implementation Test : NSObject
-(void)userLogin {
    NSString *user = @"test";
    NSString *pass = @"pass";

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"user=%@&pass=%@", user, pass];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com/login.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    sleep(50);

    NSLog(@"%@", conn);
}

@end
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  file_put_contents('/tmp/test', print_r($_POST, true));
```

Result:

```
# cat /tmp/test
Array
(
  [user] => test
  [pass] => pass
)
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. The PHP script just returns: `Array`

Comment: My script or yours? What I posted above returned exactly what I pasted -- did you run it?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Get an empty array...